# Webots using Python 2.7 when Python 3.x is default

Tags: python, webots

On my mac I switched python versions to 3.7 and when using the command `python -V` in the terminal it shows that it successfully switched. Webots still shows that the deprecated 2.7 version is being used. When I checked the command, it says `python`

I've messed with creating a `runtime.ini` as well, which seemed to work but doesn't recognize webot modules like "Controller," or "Robot." Though I can't find anything about what the module names would be and how I could include them in the Options for the `runtime.ini` with the `-m` flag.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you try to change the Python command from the Webots preferences?

Comment: When trying `python3` and `python3.7` in the command, both which work in my terminal, I get a "process crashed after starting successfully" and "Webots requires Python version 3.8, 3.7, or 2.7...", respectively

Comment: Which version of Python 3.7 do you use? The one from homebrew or from python.org or something else?

Comment: @OlivierMichel I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to me on this, I actually found a solution to my issue below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting the absolute path, shown in the image link, to a valid version of Python 3 in the Webots->Preferences command field. I had a slight error with NumPy not coming with this version but was easily fixable by doing `<absolute-path-to-version-specified> -m pip install NumPy`

I hope this is helpful to others as it was the last thing I tried and cost me some time.

[Webots preferences screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ubeb.jpg)